# How to see what is in a Selenium test variable

Tags: php, regex, selenium

I am a first time Selenium webdriver user. This is my first day at work using it to test out parts of our company's website. The environment was pre-set up for me: it is a Laravel install with Selenium testing environment, and I'm creating my tests with PhpStorm, then running them via iTerm.

I'm needing help in two areas.

1) How do I see if what a variable is storing is correct? I've successfully (according to the test output in iTerm) pulled a piece of a url out to be used later, but I have no clue how to see what exactly was stored in that variable.

2) I am having trouble pulling a piece of text off of a webpage. I've only been coding for 2 years, so this may be a "baby" question, but I am unsure how to pair php RegEx with Selenium's `$I->grabTextFrom('DIV'S CLASS');` function. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly fix this, but I'm considering it closed. Cheated the system by going to a different page and grabbing the value I wanted out of a prepopulated form field. As for printing out variables, I'm guessing the only way to do that is to slow the test down and input the variable into a field so you can see it.